# Disable Preview.app annoying delete file sound?

Tags: mac, audio, preview

How can I disable Preview.app (MacOS X) delete file sound? I. e. sound after pressing Cmd-Delete.

I tried to delete a sound file, played by Preview.app, but I haven't found that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can't, kinda

The sound you are hearing is actually the sound made by Finder deleting the file.

If you have some kind of vendetta against that sound in general, you can just delete it from the system files. That way, deleting files will be silent.

These instructions actually modify system files, so make sure you are careful. Anything you do here can be reverted by simply 'installing' Snow Leopard over the top of your existing install. This will repair all the system components, while leaving your applications and user files in place.

1. Navigate to `/System/Library/Components`. The easiest way to do this is to use the key combination Command + Shift + G, and copy-and-pasting in that path.
2. Right click `CoreAudio.component`, and select 'Show Package Contents'.
3. Now, navigate to `Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/Dock`
4. Delete `drag to trash.gif`. You would be asked to authenticate yourself.

Now, restart Finder by running  `killall Finder` in Terminal, or just restart your computer.

Comment: No, Finder makes another sound. I coudn't find a sound file player by Preview.app.

Comment: On my Snow Leopard system, they both make the same sound.

Comment: I works, thank you very much. Actually, to disable sound in Preview I had to restart Preview.